# Save_Post change Custom Post Type Post title to post id number

Tags: php, custom-post-types, save-post

I have a Custom Post Type with the slug of "sightings".

I do not need a post title, so I have removed the functionality - but now the posts are being saved as (no-title).

I read about the save_post functionality that can change the post title to something upon save? I hope thats correct.

Can someone help me write some code to achieve this? I have googled it, yes and also tried a couple of Stack Exchange snippets, but they dont seem to do anything.

Rob.

Comment: Ive used Chatsonic to generate this code.

Which does actually work. But can anyone with PHP/Wordpress knowledge forsee any issues this code might cause?

[link]https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#ien8jy1q8uclaz8ncbl3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy way to accomplish this would be to add something like this into your themes `functions.php` file:

```
function update_post(int $id, \WP_Post $post, bool $update) 
{
  // Case the post object to an array
  $data = (array) $post;
  // Set the title to the ID of the post
  $data['post_title'] = $id;
  // We need to remove the action to prevent an infinite loop
  remove_action('save_post', 'update_post');
  wp_update_post($data);
  // Finally re-add the action hook
  add_action('save_post', 'update_post', 10, 3);
}
add_action('save_post', 'update_post', 10, 3);
```

Notice that you can narrow down which post types to handle by using `add_action('save_post_{$post->post_type}', 'update_post', 10, 3);`.
So if you custom post type is called `video` then you would add the hook like this:

```
add_action('save_post_video', 'update_post', 10, 3);
```

Read more in the documentation:

- [`save_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/).
- [`save_post_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/).

Comment: Thanks, ill give this a go!! :)

Comment: I cant seem to get this working, the page just times out when clicking Publish or Update. My Custom Post Type is called "sightings". Can you help?

I have tried add_action('save_post_sightings', 'update_post', 10, 3);